# Heroku Deployment failing to see Angular components

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, gitlab, cicd

I tried to deploy my Angular application trough my gitlab pipeline to heroku. But when i check the logs it seems to error on alot of angular components/modules. This is weird because it doesn't show any errors when i try to build the application local.

Here's the link for the console error:
https://pastebin.com/LnncztUu
`gitlab logging`

I already tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it but to my suprise it didn't work. And i compiled my angular application in production mode and i found no errors also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive the missing components are fully under source control and were added to the repository. Seems like the components in your own project are missing `src/app/Shared/Services/Product.service` Not found.

Comment: No i already checked it all my files and components are added to my repo. It seems like the pipeline doesn't recognize my angular components